# jQuery each running multiple times on same element

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the below is run, assuming that male is checked, I expect jsonObj to look like this

```
0: Object
    name: "sex"
    value: "male_value"
```

However, it ends up looking like this.

```
0: Object
    name: "sex" 
    value: "male_value"
1: Object
    name: "sex" 
    value: "male_value"
2: Object
    name: "sex" 
    value: "male_value"
3: Object
    name: "sex" 
    value: "female_value"
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="form">
    <div id="radio_buttons">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male_value">Male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female_value">Female
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function jsonAdd(name, value)
{                   
    item = {};
    item ["name"] = name;
    item ["value"] = value;

    jsonObj.push(item);
}

jsonObj = [];

$("#form input").each(function() {
    //Get Input Type
    type = $(this).attr("type");
    switch(type)
    {
        case "radio":
            if($(this).prop("checked"))
            {
                var name = $(this).attr("name");
                var value = $(this).val();
                jsonAdd(name, value);
            }
        case "checkbox":
            if($(this).prop("checked"))
                {
                    var name = $(this).attr("name");
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    jsonAdd(name, value);
                }
        default:
            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var value = $(this).val();
            jsonAdd(name, value);
    }
});
```

I can seem to get it working properly if I don't use a switch statement but I don't understand why a simple switch would be causing this issue?

Comment: It looks like you have two problems. 1) You're iterating all inputs, even though you want just one value. 2) You forgot to `break` in your `switch`. To solve the first problem, one solution is to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript, like many C-like languages, will fall through from one `case` to the next if you forget to include a `break` (as noted [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#What_happens_if_I_forgot_a_break))

So:

```
switch(type)
{
    case "radio":
        if($(this).prop("checked"))
        {
            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var value = $(this).val();
            jsonAdd(name, value);
        }
        break;

    case "checkbox":
        if($(this).prop("checked"))
            {
                var name = $(this).attr("name");
                var value = $(this).val();
                jsonAdd(name, value);
            }
        break;

    default:
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var value = $(this).val();
        jsonAdd(name, value);
        break;
 }
```

should sort you out.

Comment: Oh lordy, how embarassing. My simple switch statement didn't work because I didn't even switch properly -_-

Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

You have forget to add `break` statements to your switch and in this case `default` option will run always:

```
case "radio":
    if($(this).prop("checked"))
    {
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var value = $(this).val();
        jsonAdd(name, value);
    }
    break;
case "checkbox":
....
```